# How to prevent Unity from catching and ignoring ALL exceptions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception, assertion

I am making a simple game in Unity. Because the time is limited, I don't write unit tests. Instead, I heavily employ assertions (`Debug.Assert`) and exceptions to ensure the correctness of my game logic.

However, the mechanism that I rely on to ensure the correctness is completely destroyed by the most frustrating design decision of Unity --- **it catches all exceptions and assertions and prints them in the log. Then, it continues executing the game as if nothing has happened.**

This choice of Unity makes it completely impossible for the following things:

1. The debugger breaks the program when an assertion failed or an exception is not handled
2. I can then debug through the call stack and check the variable values in watch to see what went wrong

**Hence my question**: How to prevent Unity from doing that?

### What I have tried:

In Visual Studio, `Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings`, make the debugger to break immediately if an exception is thrown, whether may be handled or not.

However, because Unity itself does not care about (to clarify: probably caught and ignored) some exceptions thrown by itself, whenever I debug my program this way, I will be overwhelmed by exceptions thrown by the Unity engine first. So this unfortunately cannot work.

Comment: `UnityEngine.Debug.Assert` doesn't throw any exception. Use `System.Diagnostics.Debug`, in the debug mode, it will automatically break the debugger by default. Or you can use your own Assert implemention and filter the specific exception.

Comment: @shingo I had tried `System.Diagnostics` before asking the question but it also didn't work. In addition, some error checking are done in exceptions, not assertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some heavy search on the Internet, I have to eventually come to implementing my own assertion function and replace all existing fatal exceptions thrown with this assertion, like @shingo suggested in comment.

Although this way I lose the type of the exceptions, at least the debugger will stop the game whenever something went wrong.

```
public static void MyDebugAssert(bool condition, String msg = "")
{
    if(!condition)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        Debugger.Log(0, "Assertion", "Debug Assertion Failed!\n" + msg);
        //ExitProcess(-1);
        Application.Quit(-1);
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, this has a major drawback --- All exceptions caused by other mistakes of mine, like `NullReferenceException`, will still be ignored. These exceptions are usually thrown when I forgot to init something or setup something correctly.

I would like to investigate further but as I stated in the question, I have limited time to implement this game, so I will just work this way for now.